# Android/iOS app store requirements for a simple cordova application that then forwards the web view to an external Javascript application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, webview

I have a Vue web app that makes use of device functionality such as camera, microphone, geolocation, and more. I want to convert this to a Cordova hybrid app that is simply used to request the required hardware permissions, as well as user login/signup functionality. This would all be local "native" code hosted by the phone's binary itself. After hardware permissions are granted, and the login/signup information is posted to my server, and validated, the user is then redirected through the web view to the web app hosted externally on my server.

Assuming the web app itself meets the Apple/Android mobile application design requirements, would I have any problems having this approved on the App/Play store?

As per Apple's [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> **4.2 Minimum Functionality**
>
> "Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website."

The web application from a WebView does look and feel like a native application (android/iOS-like animations, functionality). But it is also essentially just a "repackaged website", as it's not inherently different from the application accessed from a browser, aside from being rendered in a mobile view.

The information I've read online about this has been pretty hit or miss, and seems to be pretty dependent on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about 3rd party store policies should be directed to the 3rd party support, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Mine had three buttons at the top of the navigation that were part of the mobile app. The rest of it was just a website loaded in. That got through.